# Can't install TA-lib python issue with Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: python, windows, quantitative-finance, zipline, ta-lib

Trying to do a simple pip install TA-lib but am getting errors, in install Microsoft visual studios 14 but still the problem persists.

error code http://pastebin.com/h4jHWd1m

I tried to install it manually but get this:

```
 setup.py:77: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
      warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'talib.common' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\ta-lib\c\include -IC:\Python36-32\include -IC:\Python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tctalib/common.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\talib/common.obj
    common.c
    talib/common.c(240): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ta_libc.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

The problem seems to be the same, any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED. I had to download [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ta-lib/?source=typ_redirect) and unzip to c:\

See https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Download file TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)

then use pip install TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl